# .Net Core (replacing the Word Document Text)

Tags: .net-core

Need to Replace the few content from the word document template and convert it to PDF in .Net Core.
Opening the docx file and replacing the text based on the condition and converting it to PDF.
I am not sure which library to be used.

Comment: [Word processing (Open XML SDK)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/word-processing)

Comment: there are already plenty of examples. stackoverflow is not coding service.